# How to get rid of periods (..) in content editor web part with dynamic html elements?

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have a content editor webpart which has an empty division() and links to some javascript and and css files. The script, css and the web part is working fine as per the busines logic except the display of unwanted periods (..) on the page.

How can I get rid of the  unnecessary periods (..)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show your code because I don't know from where these periods are comming

Comment: <div>
<!--DOCTYPE html-->
<script src="../Style%20Library/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Style%20Library/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<div id="dvtest1"></div>
<div class="dvtest2"></div>
</div>

Comment: try this instead `/Style%20Library/js/test.js` without the dots

Comment: Tried giving the full path instead without the dots -  "/sites/connectu/Style%20Library/js/tooltip.js", it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: then I think that dots are coming from somewhere else

Comment: oh! I wish I could get rid of them somehow :(

Comment: Could you provide me a screenshot of your dots?